# How to validate an entered URL in android studio and if its not valid show the alert in pop up

Tags: android, xml, validation

i designed the page and initialized the edit text and the button to validate the url and aligned the UI for this ,

> the basic need for me is to validate the url which user enter in the edit-text while clicking the button
>   if the url is valid it should redirect to the web page or show a valid pop-up
>   if url is not valid it should show and error pop-up

/*main activity code */

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button check;
    EditText text1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_check);
        text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_url);

        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                         //
                          }
```

/*java*/

/*xml*/

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_url"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Enter Url Here.."
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Check"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_url"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
```

/*xml*///////

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(potentialUrl).matches()
```

It will return True if **URL is valid** and false if **URL is invalid.**

And simple show alert dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this method to validate a url

```
private boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
    Pattern pattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;
    Matcher matcher= pattern.matcher(url.toLowerCase());
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Inside your onclick

```
       if (isValidUrl(url)) {
           // Open webview

         } else {
            // show dialog
         }
```

Comment: :- can you please write the code for me i tried your code its not working

Comment: i added the method inside my MainActivity.java as you said intialized the method and after that added the condition in inside onclik but its not working can you share a working code??

Comment: can you come on whatsapp 8220044525

Comment: sure@Indra Kumar S